# How can I get the URL address from the browser in ReactJS (servers URL)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I can parse are HTTP response of one of the intial calls and save that in the state but there must be another way to get the URL?

I am using the npm 'rest' library and want to specify a different port but I do not know the path on which machine the server will be installed so I need the server's url.

**Solution**

window.location.hostname

Comment: window.location.href

Comment: Thanks I just found that as well :)

Comment: Why down vote this, I spent time googling for a answer and trying different things.  All of them were related to the clients IP not server.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you should mark the correct answer (not write solution in your own question). If no answers are correct, and you found your own solution, submit that as an answer and mark it correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current URL in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/get-current-url-in-javascript)

Comment: @Chris          at the time there was no answer provided so I posted the solution I used which was also a comment.   I later marked the answer correct when the user posted it not just in comments.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`location` is a property on the `window` object with a bunch of information, you can get the url with `window.location.href`

You can get the hostname with `window.location.hostname`

Comment: Thanks for some reason I didnt think I had access to this.  I just found it prior to your answer ;)

Comment: nit: window.location doesn't return anything. It's not a function.